# Convert date to M j, Y? In Javascript

Tags: javascript

Current I have this var called `uniqueDate`

and If I try to get the value of this variable `console.log(uniqueDate);`

This will give me a log in inspect element like this

`["2020-05-24", "2020-05-25", "2020-05-26", "2020-05-27", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-29"]`

In php there's `date('M j, Y',strtotime(<data>))`

that will result something like this

`May 24, 2020`

`May 25, 2020`

`May 26, 2020`

`May 27, 2020`

`May 28, 2020`

`May 29, 2020`

I want to convert the date format of var `uniqueDate` to `M j, Y` like the sample date above.

Using Jquery? or just JS

Comment: Use a date library like moment.js or date-fns

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this:

```js
var date = new Date('2020-05-24');
var normalizedDate = new Date(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * -60000);
var formattedDate = normalizedDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'short',
    year: 'numeric'
});
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dates = ["2020-05-24", "2020-05-25", "2020-05-26", "2020-05-27", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-29"]
  var data = [];
  for (var date of dates)
  {
    date = new Date(date);
    var final = date.toDateString();
    var final = final.substring(4, 15);
    data.push(final);
  }
  console.log(data);
```

With this line of code 'var final = final.substring(4, 15);' The result is as following

```
[ 'May 24 2020',
  'May 25 2020',
  'May 26 2020',
  'May 27 2020',
  'May 28 2020',
  'May 29 2020' ]
```

Without this line of code 'var final = final.substring(4, 15);' it will be as following

```
[ 'Sun May 24 2020',
  'Mon May 25 2020',
  'Tue May 26 2020',
  'Wed May 27 2020',
  'Thu May 28 2020',
  'Fri May 29 2020' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. Just create a new Javascript Date object and call toDateString() method from that object. If you do not need the day of week, just call the substring method

```js
String.prototype.insert = function(index,str){
  return this.slice(0,index) + str + this.slice(index)
   }


var a = new Date('2020-05-27');
console.log(a.toDateString());
console.log(a.toDateString().substring(4));
console.log(a.toDateString().substring(4).insert(-5, ','));
```

Comment: @MisterJojo Changes made to answer for the comma

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of moment.js if you're working a lot with dates, but for simple formatting, this is about as close as you'll get to the PHP way:

```
let uniqueDate = [ // better to call it uniqueDates
  "2020-05-24",
  "2020-05-25",
  "2020-05-26",
  "2020-05-27",
  "2020-05-28",
  "2020-05-29"
]

let formatedDates = uniqueDate.map((arr) => {
  let date = new Date(arr)
  var options = { month: "short", day: "numeric", year: "numeric" }
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(date)
})

console.log(formatedDates)
// ["May 23, 2020", "May 24, 2020", "May 25, 2020", "May 26, 2020", "May 27, 2020", "May 28, 2020"]
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3dymjh9/

Answer (score 1):

pure JS code,
-  juste use the function named **convertDate**

```js
const convertDate = dx => (new Date(dx)).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { month: 'short', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' });

for (let dt of ["2020-05-24", "2020-05-25", "2020-05-26", "2020-05-27", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-29"])
  {
  document.write( convertDate(dt) , '<br>')
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by creating `months` object. we can even customize it when it comes to different months than English months.

```js
const list = ["2020-05-24", "2020-05-25", "2020-05-26", "2020-05-27", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-29"];

const monthObj = {
    "01": "January",
    "02": "February",
    "03": "March",
    "04": "April",
    "05": "May",
    "06": "June",
    "07": "July",
    "08": "August",
    "09": "September",
    "10": "October",
    "11": "November",
    "12": "December",
}

const formattedList = list.map((item, index) => {
    const arr = item.split('-');
    const year = arr[0];
    const month = arr[1];
    const day = arr[2];
    return monthObj[month] + " " + day +
        ", " + year;
})

console.log(formattedList)
```